# using malloc in dgels function of lapacke

Tags: malloc, lapacke

i am trying to use dgels function of lapacke:
when i use it with malloc fucntion. it doesnot give correct value.
can anybody tell me please what is the mistake when i use malloc and create a matrix?
thankyou

```
 /* Calling DGELS using row-major order */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main ()
{
double a[3][2] = {{1,0},{1,1},{1,2}};

double **outputArray;
int designs=3;
int i,j,d,i_mal;
lapack_int info,m,n,lda,ldb,nrhs;
double outputArray[3][1] = {{6},{0},{0}};*/



outputArray = (double**) malloc(3* sizeof(double*)); 
for(i_mal=0;i_mal<3;i_mal++)
{
outputArray[i_mal] = (double*) malloc(1* sizeof(double));  
}
for (i=0;i<designs;i++)
{
printf("put first value");
scanf("%lf",&outputArray[i][0]);
}

m = 3;
n = 2;
nrhs = 1;
lda = 2;
ldb = 1;




info = LAPACKE_dgels(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'N',m,n,nrhs,*a,lda,*outputArray,ldb);

for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<nrhs;j++)
{
printf("%lf ",outputArray[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}
getch();
```

return (info);
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from `outputArray` not being contiguous in memory. You may use something like this instead :

```
 outputArray = (double**) malloc(3* sizeof(double*)); 
 outputArray[0]=(double*) malloc(3* sizeof(double));
 for (i=0;i<designs;i++){
     outputArray[i]=&outputArray[0][i];
 }
```

Don't forget to free the memory !

```
 free(outputArray[0]);
 free(outputArray);
```

Edit : Contiguous means that you have to allocate the memory for all values at once. See http://www.fftw.org/doc/Dynamic-Arrays-in-C_002dThe-Wrong-Way.html#Dynamic-Arrays-in-C_002dThe-Wrong-Way : some packages, like fftw or lapack require this feature for optimization. As you were calling malloc three times, you created three parts and things went wrong.

If you have a single right hand side, there is no need for a 2D array (`double**`). `outputArray[i]` is a `double*`, that is, the start of the i-th row ( row major). The right line may be `outputArray[i]=&outputArray[0][i*nrhs];` if you have many RHS.

By doing this in your code, you are building a 3 rows, one column, that is one RHS. The solution, is of size `n=2`. It should be `outputArray[0][0] , outputArray[1][0]`. I hope i am not too wrong, check this on simple cases !

Bye,

Comment: thanx :)
it works very well. but i have few questions:

what does contiguous means in memory? when we store a space for matrix it is not contiguous? why we have to still use "&" to store values? and last why we use ouputArray[0][i], i second; while first brackets are for rows, and here either we have either 3 rows or 3 columns by doing this?

Comment: yes you are right. but how can we manage in case of 2d array:
 for matix **a. i created 2d array malloc by doing so:

 double **a;
 a=(double**)malloc(3* sizeof(double*));
 for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{
a[i]=(double*)malloc(2* sizeof(double));
}

so now the answer come wrong. 
how can we write malloc in this 2d matrix so that lapack gives right answer.