# using malloc in dgels function of lapack

Tags: c, malloc, lapack

When I use  `malloc` fucntion in the first matrix. it doesn't give correct value. but without `malloc` it gives correct answer.can anybody tell me please what is the mistake when I use `malloc` and create a matrix and storing them on contiguous places?

```
/* Calling DGELS using row-major order */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main ()
{
    //  double a[6][2] = {{1,2},{1,4},{1,6},{1,8},{1,10},{1,12}};

    //double outputArray[3][1];
    int designs=6;
    double **a;


    int i,j,d,i_mal;
    lapack_int info,m,n,lda,ldb,nrhs;
    //double outputArray[6][1] = {{2},{4},{4},{5},{5},{7}};
    double **outputArray;

    a=(double**)malloc(6* sizeof(double*));
    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        a[i]=(double*)malloc(2* sizeof(double));
    }
    //for storing them on particular places
    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            outputArray[i]=&outputArray[j][i];
        }
    }
    //putting values
    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("put a[%d][%d]",i,j);
            scanf("%lf",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    outputArray = (double**) malloc(6* sizeof(double*)); 
    outputArray[0]=(double*) malloc(6* sizeof(double));
    for (i=0;i<designs;i++)
    {
        outputArray[i]=&outputArray[0][i];
    }

    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        printf("put first value");
        scanf("%lf",&outputArray[i][0]);
    }


    m = 6;
    n = 2;
    nrhs = 1;
    lda = 2;
    ldb = 1;

    info = LAPACKE_dgels(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'N',m,n,nrhs,*a,lda,*outputArray,ldb);
    printf("\n coefficients are:");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < nrhs; j++)
        {
            printf("%lf ",outputArray[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();

    return (info);
}
```

Comment: `malloc` allocates memory, it gives no guarantees about where that memory will be allocated, or if it will be contiguous. Insofar as the return value is not `NULL`, I don't see how `malloc` could return an "Incorrect Value."

Comment: What exactly is the idea behind the first two loops around this line `outputArray[i]=&outputArray[j][i];`. As in any case it provokes undefined behaviour as `outputArray` points "nowhere", will say has never been initialised.

Comment: sorry, it should be a matrix instead of outputArray in first storing them. the problem lies in using 2d malloc in lapack. when i use it, the results are wrong. may the fact lies in lapack uses static c matrix. but i have to use malloc. so how can i convert dynamic array to static. thankyou

Comment: @Mgetz I've never seen a `malloc()` implementation that returns non-contiguous memory... How would that even work? (Unless you meant contiguous relative to previously returned memory chunks, that is.)

Comment: @twalberg each call to `malloc` returns a block of contiguous memory, it does not guarantee that each call will be contiguous to each other.

Comment: @Mgetz Right... Just making sure that's what you meant. In fact, many implementations pretty much guarantee that consecutively allocated blocks *won't* be consecutive in memory due to the addition of heap-management metadata to each block...

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer to [using malloc in dgels function of lapacke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138259/using-malloc-in-dgels-function-of-lapacke/23143673#23143673), you may use the same trick for the matrix `a` :

```
    double** a=malloc(m*sizeof(double*));
    if(a==NULL){printf("malloc failed\n");}
    a[0]=malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));
    if(a[0]==NULL){printf("malloc failed\n");}
    for (i=0;i<m;i++){
        a[i]=&a[0][i*n];
    }
```

The full code, including `free` to free the memory :

```
/* Calling DGELS using row-major order */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "lapacke.h"
//#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main ()
{
    //double a[3][2] = {{1,0},{1,1},{1,2}};

    double **outputArray;
    int designs=3;
    int i,j,d,i_mal;
    lapack_int info,m,n,lda,ldb,nrhs;

    m = 3;
    n = 2;
    nrhs = 4;
    lda = n;
    ldb = nrhs;

    //double outputArray[3][1] = {{6},{0},{0}};
    double** a=malloc(m*sizeof(double*));
    if(a==NULL){printf("malloc failed\n");}
    a[0]=malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));
    if(a[0]==NULL){printf("malloc failed\n");}
    for (i=0;i<m;i++){
        a[i]=&a[0][i*n];
    }
    a[0][0]=1;
    a[0][1]=0;
    a[1][0]=1;
    a[1][1]=1;
    a[2][0]=1;
    a[2][1]=2;


    outputArray = malloc(m* sizeof(double*));
    if(outputArray==NULL){printf("malloc failed\n");}
    outputArray[0]=malloc(m*nrhs* sizeof(double));
    if(outputArray[0]==NULL){printf("malloc failed\n");}
    for (i=0;i<m;i++){
        outputArray[i]=&outputArray[0][i*nrhs];
    }

    for (i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        printf("put first value");
        scanf("%lf",&outputArray[i][0]);
    }



    info = LAPACKE_dgels(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'N',m,n,nrhs,*a,lda,*outputArray,ldb);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<nrhs;j++)
        {
            printf("%lf ",outputArray[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //getch();

    free(a[0]);
    free(a);
    free(outputArray[0]);
    free(outputArray);
    return (info);
}
```